# Transform jquery in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you transfrom this from jquery library into pure javascript?

```
function appendText(){
    var text = $("#text").val();

    if ( $("#text").val() ){
    var textArea = "<div class='divex'> <li style='list-style-type:none;' id='t"+counter+"'>"+text+"</li><button id='b"+
    counter+"'name='t"+counter+"' >edit</button></div>";    
    $("#text").val();
    $("#addedText").after(textArea);
    $("#t"+counter).clear;    
    $("#t"+counter).attr('readonly','readonly');
    $("#b"+counter).bind('click',makeAreaEditable);
    $("#text").val('');
    $('.divex').sortable();                                                 
    counter++;
    }
    else{
    }   
};
```

for the start i tried something like this:

```
var counter=0;
function appendText(){
    var text = document.getElementById('text');

    if ( document.getElementById('text').value ){
    var textArea = "<div class='divex'> <li style='list-style-type:none;'id='t"+counter+"'>"+text+"</li><button id='b"+
    counter+"'name='t"+counter+"' >edit</button> </div>";

    var texty = document.getElementById('addedText').appendChild(textArea);
```

but i have some problems.

> I think i didn't atribue the text to the list corectly.. Here is what
>   i've got so far:

```
 var counter=0;
    function appendText(){

        var text = document.getElementById('text').value;

        if ( document.getElementById('text').value ){   
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.class = 'divex';
        var li = document.createElement('li');

        div.appendChild(li);
        document.createTextNode(text);

        var bigdiv = document.getElementById('addedText');
        bigdiv.appendChild(text);

        counter++;
        }
        else{
        }   
    };
```

Comment: `but i have some problems.` - me too. Could you be more specific about the problems you are having?

Comment: Try to update your question and specify what have you tried and what did not work. That will help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Questions regarding refactoring working code should be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `$('.divex').sortable();` – that’s probably a couple of thousand vanilla JS lines right there...

Comment: you can ignore the sortable function... i just need the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.appendChild()` expects a DOM element, not a HTML string like you have in your `textarea` variable.

You have to use `document.createElement` first, something like:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.class = 'divex';
var li = document.createElement('li');
div.appendChild(li);
// etc.
```

Then use `document.createTextNode()` to create the text inside the `li`-element. And so on..

Comment: Thank you i'll get back to you right away

Comment: I've uppgraded my code... what i've done wrong?

Comment: You have to save the return value of `createTextNode` and pass that into the `appendChild` call. Also why are you passing `text` to your last `bigDiv.appendChild`? Shouldn't it be the newly generated DOM tree?